# How to fetch value based on div class and ID combination

Tags: jquery

I have a div as shown below

```
<div class="lastItm_Wrap" id="lastwrap707" data-lastwrapquan="0">
   <div class="Itm_right_aside">
      <p class="additionsclassstyle" style="display:block;"><span>Additions:</span>  <b class="additions">0</b></p>
   </div>
</div>


<div class="lastItm_Wrap" id="lastwrap709" data-lastwrapquan="0">
   <div class="Itm_right_aside">
      <p class="additionsclassstyle" style="display:block;"><span>Additions:</span>  <b class="additions">0</b></p>
   </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to fetch the Text of additions , i was trying this way

```
var vendoritemsid = '707' ;

var addtions=$(".lastItm_Wrap #lastwrap"+vendoritemsid).find('.Itm_right_aside . additions').text();

alert(addtions);
```

but i am getting blank alert

THis is my fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/fpzeLa0a/8/

could you please let me know how to fetch te additions class text ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the selector `$(".lastItm_Wrap #lastwrap707")` wasn't selecting any elements.

The element `.lastItm_Wrap` actually *has* an `id`, therefore you would remove the space between the selectors (because you aren't trying to select a descendant).

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/9rwggqty/)

```
var vendoritemsid = '707';
var addtions= $(".lastItm_Wrap#lastwrap" + vendoritemsid).find('.Itm_right_aside .additions').text();

alert(addtions);
```

Since you're selecting an element with a unique `id`, you could just omit the class selector.

[**Example Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/toap2nts/)

```
$("#lastwrap" + vendoritemsid + ' .Itm_right_aside .additions').text();
```

The `.find()` method can also be removed.